# JSF - Java - EJB

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3

I am new to J2EE and having problem with EJB. I already have a JSF form that is working fine. I am adding a new field to this form and binding it to the java class (1), adding getter and setter methods to the corresponding java class (2) and trying to send this object to my analyzer class (3) (which analyzes the form objects and uses them for getting queries from the database). 
1).jsf

```
<td>
     <webuijsf:label for="textArea333" text="fee"/>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
      <webuijsf:textArea binding="#{user$form.test}" id="textArea333" rows="1" required="true"/>
   </td>
```

2)  .java

```
    public TextArea test = new TextArea();
    public TextArea getTest(){
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(TextArea test){
        this.test = test;
    }
 System.out.println("test in java class " + tested); // works fine
 request.addParameter("test", tested); // request object is used for sending data to //analyzer class
 System.out.println(request.toString()); // works fine
```

3) analyzer class:
...

```
else if (argument.getReportArgument().getName().equals("netcost")) {
                        netcost = (Integer) argument.getValue().getObject();
                        System.out.println("netcost" + cost); // works fine
}else if(argument.getReportArgument().getName().equals("test")){
                        test = (Integer)argument.getValue().getObject();
                        System.out.println("test" + test); // doesn't work.
}
```

It is working fine until step 3, but I can not reach my test argument from my analyzer class. I can reach other arguments (like the one above - cost argument), but I can not reach my newly-created argument. Should I do extra sth for my analyzer class? Do you have any opinion about what am I missing? As I said I am new to J2EE, I may be skipping one important step..

Comment: Why do you use a HTTP request for communication between two objects on the same server? Or am I misunderstanding your design?

Comment: Do you mean request.addparameter? I am sorry for causing misunderstanding but my request object is of class Request that I created. I am not using HTTP Request..

Comment: @lamostreta, we need to see more of your project. How are you getting a reference of your analizer class on the bean class (#2)? Are you using EJB annotation? Please post at least the #2 class fully, if you can.